# Need clarifying on basic derivatives of natural log/e

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So here's the question:

> Find the derivative: $ y= e^{\cos(x)}$
>
> > Hint: This is a combination of the chain rule and the natural log. The derivative is $(\ln a)(a^{f(x)}) * f'(x)$

So normally without using the hint I would use the chain rule and solve it like this:

$e^{\cos(x)} * -\sin(x)$

simplified....

$-\sin x(e^{\cos(x)})$

Apparently though, according to the hint provided, there should be an $ln (e)$ which cancels out, so it should look like this:

$e^{\cos(x)} * -\sin(x)* \ln e$,
where the $\ln e$ simplifies to $1$ and has no affect on the final answer.

So when I did it, I only used the chain rule. The answer ended up the same, but I was wondering if this was a coincidence or if it is always like that. If I continue doing it my way will I be fine?

Sorry if this is a dumb question. It's been a while since I took Calculus 1 and I'm starting Calculus 2 now so I'm a bit rusty.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $f(x)=e^{\cos x}$ is $f'(x)=e^{\cos x} (-\sin x)$. So you are correct.

The trick is that using your hint, the derivative of $a^x$ is $(\ln a)(a^{f(x)}) f'(x)$, allows you to simplify $\ln a$ when $a=e$. Thus, whenever you have an integral of the form $a^x$ where $a=e$, you can always simplify the $\ln$ term in the derivative.

This also implies that $f(x)=f'(x)$ when $f(x)=e^x.$

EDIT: I just want to clarify that your way will always work, because it sounds like you are doing the in-your-head simplification of $\ln (e)= 1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a coincidence as you predicted but a special case for $e^{f(x)}$ since $ln(e) = 1$. For example: if the question were $y = a^{cos(x)}$, your answer would be $\frac{dy}{dx} = (ln(a))(a^{cos(x)})(-sin(x))$.

Comment: I see, thank you! What if the question was $y=2a^{cos(x)}$, would it still work the same way?

Comment: Yes. Use the constant rule: $\frac{dy}{dx}(af(x)) = a*\frac{dy}{dx}(f(x))$